# How to Print Spelled out month names rather than numbers

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

How can you get Perl to print names of months rather than their numbers for example: 9 should appear as September. I would like the program below to print names of months rather than their numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Easter;

print "Please enter a year";
chomp (my $year = <STDIN>);

my ($m1, $d1) = easter ($year);
my ($m2, $d2) = julian_easter ($year);
my ($m3, $d3) = orthodox_easter ($year);

print "Gregorian => Month: $m1 Day: $d1\n";
print "Julian    => Month: $m2 Day: $d2\n";
print "Orthodox  => Month: $m3 Day: $d3\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm too lazy to download this module to see if months are from 0 to 11 or 1 to 12. For this, I'm assuming months are from 0 to 11.

Easiest way is to create an array with the month names:

```
my @month_list = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);

my ($m1, $d1) = easter ($year);
my ($m2, $d2) = julian_easter ($year);
my ($m3, $d3) = orthodox_easter ($year);

print "Gregorian => Month: $month_list[$m1] Day: $d1\n";
print "Julian    => Month: $month_list[$m2] Day: $d2\n";
print "Orthodox  => Month: $month_list[$m3] Day: $d3\n";
```

If months are numbered from 1 to 12, add a fake month to the beginning of the array:

```
my @month_list = qw(Foo Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);
```

Comment: It's my allergies. I hate May.

Comment: ya i noticed that when i added the code, i just added may in there :D...great help though

Answer (score 5):

I'm using buil-in `POSIX` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Easter;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my %dispach_sub = (
    easter          => \&easter,
    julian_easter   => \&julian_easter,
    orthodox_easter => \&orthodox_easter,
);

print "Please enter a year: ";
chomp( my $year = <STDIN> );

foreach my $key ( keys %dispach_sub ) {

    print "[$key]\t";
    my ( $month, $day ) = $dispach_sub{$key}->($year);
    print POSIX::strftime( "Month: %B Day: %d",
        0, 0, 0, $day, $month - 1, $year - 1900 ),
      "\n";
}
```