# Convert ISO Date to DD-MON-YYYY in a csv file in unix

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

I've csv file containing date in ISO format like below.

```
id,x1,x2,x3
AIR,Partner,2015-10-20T04:00:00.000Z,2015-10-20T04:00:00.000Z,2016-02-12T05:00:00.000Z
CMX,Partner,Tier,2017-03-23T04:00:00.000Z
WKA,Partner,Tier,2017-05-22T04:00:00.000Z
APP,Partner,2017-10-04T04:00:00.000Z,Tier
BUN,2017-09-27T04:00:00.000Z,Partner,,2017-09-27T04:00:00.000Z
```

There is no fix column for date it can appear in any column except 1st column.

I want to convert all occurrence of ISO date into DD-MON-YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format.

Please help.

Comment: See [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following through a UNIX pipe:

`sed -E 's#\b([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z\b#\3/\2/\1#g'`

Another option would be the following PCRE, which explicitly enforces the `,` separator at the start (as you mention this field cannot be the first one), and either `,` or EOL at the end of the matched expression:

`cat | perl -pe 's#,\K([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z(?=,|$)#$3/$2/$1#g'`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the previous answer with [How to Print Spelled out month names rather than numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800862/how-to-print-spelled-out-month-names-rather-than-numbers) to get the following two options, depending on which of the two answers you like best:

---

- The first option is to not use any libraries, but just use the direct embedding of the names of the months:

  `cat 48941818.txt | perl -pe '@m = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec); s#,\K([0-9]{4})-([01][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z(?=,|$)#$3-$m[$2]-$1#g'`

---

- The second option is to use http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime as in [C](http://mdoc.su/-/strftime.3), and treat the replace part as perl code with the `e` modifier, as per [Embedding evaluations in Perl regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250942/embedding-evaluations-in-perl-regex), and, ultimately, as documented at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace, which makes it extra flexible as you can do further improvements to the date format (although on my system `%v` didn't work, and `%e` had extra space in one-digit days).

  `% cat 48941818.txt | perl -pe 'use POSIX qw(strftime); s#,\K([0-9]{4})-([01][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])T([0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z(?=,|$)#POSIX::strftime(qw/%e-%b-%Y/,0,0,$4,$3,$2-1,$1-1900)#ge'
  id,x1,x2,x3
  AIR,Partner,20-Oct-2015,20-Oct-2015,12-Feb-2016
  CMX,Partner,Tier,23-Mar-2017
  WKA,Partner,Tier,22-May-2017
  APP,Partner, 4-Oct-2017,Tier
  BUN,27-Sep-2017,Partner,,27-Sep-2017
  %`